Firestore restore from automatic backup
I understand how manual import/export of database works in firestore.
What's bugging me is why is it not possible to import data from automatic disaster recovery daily backup the same way (to the same database), but only to a new database in the same project. How does this even work, I didn't find detailed info in the docs.
I thought what I needed was in-place restore given the sentence "An in-place restore lets you restore a database from a backup to the source database that created the backup". However, it also states "A restore operation must use a destination database that doesn't already exist.". To me, this seems like conflicting information.

If you have a problem with any page of the documentation, you can use the "send feedback" button at the top of the page to express your confusion or concern.  You can also contact Firebase support directly. But I think it's important to read the rest of the page to get the specific instructions on how to work with the backups in a way that's consistent with what you're reading.  "You can, however, simulate an in-place restore by deleting the source database and then restoring from a backup to a new database with the same name as the source database."
